# Horizontal Scroll is not working in MAUI. What am I missing or is this a bug?

Tags: c#, maui, .net-maui, maui-windows

If I make a brand new MAUI desktop app (using Visual Studio Version 17.3.0 Preview 4.0 or previous), I am unable to get horizontalscrollbar to show in ScrollView.
If you've messed with MAUI, you know that when you make a new project, you get some canned content ("Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"). Starting with that - the vertical scroll bar does show up as expected (see right side of attached image).
[image]

But how to get the horizontal one to show up? I've cut out everything but the image (including the VerticalStackLayout and even added HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage">
    <ScrollView HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
        <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                 WidthRequest="800"
                 />
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

but still no horizontal scroll. Any ideas? Is it a bug?

EDIT: Based on comment, I've changed the picture to be more clear...to show how the vertical scroll appears but the horizontal does not appear when the content is larger in both directions.

Comment: If the content is not wider than it’s container it won’t need to scroll

Comment: Sorry the image was not clear. I've changed it to reflect the problem more clearly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to their answer at https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9000
you can just add `Orientation` property on `ScrollView`.

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Both" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
<Image 
    Source="dotnet_bot.png"
    SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
    WidthRequest="800"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the case as you said.

And I have created a new issue about this problem.

You can follow it up here:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9000 .

Thank you very much for your feedback and patience.